How can I add multiple dots using decorator in my calendar?
I am using the prolificinteractive material-calendarview, and I also have schedules in the calendar. I already have 1 dot to represent that the day has a schedule on it.This is what my calendar looks like now What I want to know is how can I add multiple dots for different schedules that are on the same day?
This is where I set up my calendar
 private fun setupCalendarView() {
        mBinding.calendarView.setOnDateChangedListener { _, date, _ ->
            val selectedDate = "${date.day}/${date.month + 1}/${date.year}"
            showToast(selectedDate)
        }

        mMainViewModel.schedules.observe(this) { schedules ->
            if (schedules != null) {
                val occupiedDates = schedules.mapNotNull { stringToCalendarDay(it.date) }.toSet()
                Log.d("Get Schedule", "Occupied Dates: $occupiedDates")
                val decorator = OccupiedDateDecorator(occupiedDates)
                mBinding.calendarView.removeDecorators() // Clear existing decorators
                mBinding.calendarView.addDecorator(decorator)
                mBinding.calendarView.invalidateDecorators() // Force refresh of decorators
            }
        }
    }

    private fun setupAddScheduleButton() {
        mBinding.buttonAddSchedule.setOnClickListener {
            val userId = getUserId()
            val intent = Intent(this, AddScheduleActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("USER_ID", userId)
            startActivity(intent)

        }
    }

   private fun stringToCalendarDay(dateString: String): CalendarDay? {
        return try {
            val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault())
            val date = sdf.parse(dateString)
            val calendar = Calendar.getInstance().apply { time = date }
            CalendarDay.from(
                calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1,
                calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
            )
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            null
        }
    }

My decorator for the calendar
class OccupiedDateDecorator(private val dates: Set<CalendarDay>) : DayViewDecorator {

    override fun shouldDecorate(day: CalendarDay): Boolean {
        return dates.contains(day)
    }

    override fun decorate(view: DayViewFacade) {
        view.addSpan(DotSpan(5f, Color.RED)) // Adding a red dot below the date
    }
}

